# randomly controlling the percentage of non zero values in a matrix using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, scipy

I am looking to create matrices with different levels of sparsity. I intend to do that by converting all the values that are nonzero in the data matrix to 1's and the remaining entries would be 0.

I was able to achieve that using the following code. But I am not sure how would I be able to randomly make the 1's to 0's in the final matrix with control on the percentage of 1's.

For eg:

the numpy.random.choice

> numpy.random.randint(2, size = data_shape, p=[0.75,0.25])

enables us to create matrices with control over the percentage of 1's. How do I control the percentage of 1's in a similar way in the final matrix?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
import numpy.ma as ma

indptr = np.array([0, 2, 3, 6])
indices = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
matrix = sp.csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=(3, 3)).toarray()
print(matrix)

mask = ma.masked_greater(matrix, 0)
print(mask)
print(mask.mask)

matrix2 = mask.mask
int_matrix = matrix2.astype(int)
print(int_matrix)
```

Output:

```
Data matrix:
[[1 0 2]
 [0 0 3]
 [4 5 6]]
Masked matrix:
[[-- 0 --]
 [0 0 --]
 [-- -- --]]
Masked values:
[[ True False  True]
 [False False  True]
 [ True  True  True]]
Final matrix
[[1 0 1]
 [0 0 1]
 [1 1 1]]
```

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: So, if I understood it correctly, let's say you have an array with 25% 1s. Then, you would like to modify to make it say 20% 1s, but use only the already set 1s to 0s?

Comment: @Divakar yes that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this -

```
idx = np.flatnonzero(a)
N = np.count_nonzero(a!=0) - int(round(0.25*a.size))
np.put(a,np.random.choice(idx,size=N,replace=False),0)
```

**Sample run**

1) Input array :

```
In [259]: a
Out[259]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

2) Get the non-zero indices :

```
In [260]: idx = np.flatnonzero(a)
```

3) Get the number of non-zeros to be set as zeros :

```
In [261]: N = np.count_nonzero(a!=0) - int(round(0.25*a.size))
```

4) Finally we select N randomly chosen indices from idx and set those in `a` as zeros :

```
In [262]: np.put(a,np.random.choice(idx,size=N,replace=False),0)
```

5) Verify array -

```
In [263]: a
Out[263]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

6) Finally, we see the percentage of non-zeros and verify it to be `25%` :

```
In [264]: np.count_nonzero(a!=0)/float(a.size)
Out[264]: 0.25
```